# MinGW program crashes when dynamically linking but not when statically linking

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw32

I am using MSYS2 provided MinGW32 and QTCreator together with CMake. I have written a very basic class (to be completed later) as a shared library. My main program has an instance of this class as a member of one of its classes.

Essentially my shared library looks like:

```
// MyClass.h
class MyClass { public: MyClass(); };

// MyClass.cpp
#include "MyClass.h"
MyClass::MyClass() { }
```

And my program looks like:

```
// B.h

#include "MyClass.h"

class B
{
    public:
    // Some stuff here.

    private:
    MyClass  m_other;
};
```

When I statically link, all is fine. When I dynamically link, the program crashes, and GDB cannot get a stack trace. It looks like the program doesn't even really start.

Using nm on the shared DLL I see something like:

```
61c41604 T __ZN9MyClassC1Ev
61c41604 T __ZN9MyClassC2Ev
```

I guess these are the constructors.

Using nm on the program I see:

```
00414388 I __imp___ZN9MyClassC1Ev
```

There is no .lib generated by the build process.

My CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
add_library(MyLib SHARED
    MyClass.cpp
)
```

I would much prefer to link dynamically so if anyone can help me with this I would be very grateful.

Comment: Does this happen when you link to an empty library?  Does this happen when you link to your normal library but don't call any functions from it?   Does this happen when you link to a simple library with one C function? Does this happen when your main program only has an empty main() function? So many things you can check yourself...

Comment: If I dynamically link but do not call any functions or instantiate any objects from my library then it doesn't crash. If my main() is empty then I am not calling any functions so obviously it doesn't crash as per the previous answer. I haven't tried with a library with a single C function, but yes I am sure it would crash. I am pretty certain that the problem is the disparity in the symbols which I think would be solved by generating a .lib for my library.

Comment: I have tried using WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS in my CMakeLists.txt. It didn't work.

Comment: I have tried using __declspec(dllexport)/__declspec(dllimport) as per https://cmake.org/Wiki/BuildingWinDLL. It didn't work.

Comment: I now have a similar issue trying to link to a 3rd party library. They have provided a DLL with all symbols stripped out. They have provided a .lib for which "nm" reports: `I __imp__FT_GetDeviceInfoList@8` and `T _FT_GetDeviceInfoList@8`. My static library has an undefined reference to __imp__FT_GetDeviceInfoList@8.

Comment: It is common practice to use dllexport when building a dll, and to use dllimport when building a component that uses a dll. Appropriate declspecs have to be in your source code. I have no idea how you can do this without.

Comment: @n.m. I tried that but it didn't work (see above). Reading up some more I found that MinGW, being Posix based, exports all symbols automatically, the same way that shared libraries work on Linux and Unix systems. I also found that normally if you don't do the dllexport it won't even link. In my case it does link (presumably because the symbols are present in the MyLibrary.dll.a file).

Comment: My current best guess is that I could get this to work if I specified static linking by the executable while building the library as shared. This way the executable would link to the MyLibrary.dll.a file which has the code to correctly load the DLL at runtime in the same way as a .lib file usually works. However the CMake file specifies the library as SHARED. To work around this would be very messy.

Comment: I have been looking into this more after a third party DLL completely failed to link. Apparently linking to third party DLLs is fraught with danger with all sorts of problems such as varying ABIs to deal with. However this is a library built from scratch with not only the same environment but the same build command as the executable to which I want to link!